# How to make use of session in REST API

Tags: php, rest

I saw in some company REST web-service documentation ,in step1 asking for APIkey and they will return server time and expiry time and auth_key as a response. In step2 for login user name password and md5 of both apikey and auth_key it will return session ID. In remaining step user only to send session id. how it possible?by session? I'm confused, please help me anyone regarding this.

Comment: How is what possible, exactly?

Comment: i'm new to the REST API so i searched to make use of Session in REST API  :some answers in stack overflow i seen that ,using of session in REST API not possible, because we not receiving direct request from browser so difficult to maintain session.but in this documentation they said about session id,that's why i confused,its possible  or not

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They aren't actually making use of a `session` in the sense of a PHP `session_start()`. What they're really doing can be explained in a few steps:

1. You ask for an API key:

   1. The service then generates an `auth_key` with a lifetime
   2. Saves the generated `api key`, `auth_key` and `expiry` to a database table. The `api key` is **very likely** a UNIQUE index on the table.
   3. Sends a response to the user containing the generated `api key`, `auth_key` and the `expiry` of the keys.
2. You send your login details, along with the `md5(api_key . auth_key)`: I expect that you likely also send the `api key` along in a header.

   1. It first uses the received `api key` to query the database table
   2. Retrieves the `auth_key` value and expiry
   3. Checks that the `auth_key` has not expired; if it hasn't
   4. Computes the `md5(api_key . auth_key)`
   5. Compares it to the `md5(api_key . auth_key)` from your request
   6. If it is the same, then it checks your login details
   7. If the login details are correct, it generates a unique `session_id` associated to the `authenticated account`
   8. It saves these details to another database table: `session_id`, `account_id`. I'm using **account id** here because it's the most likely to use.
   9. It returns this `session_id` to your client
3. Every request you send after that with the `session_id` then works like so:

   1. It retrieve the `session_id` from the request
   2. It tries to retrieve the account associated to the `session_id` from the database
   3. If found/valid and you have access/permissions to perform the operation, it executes the command.

In summary, that is the entire flow; which is why I said earlier that it doesn't use sessions in the way sessions work when you do a `session_start()`; meaning they can't do something like `$_SESSION`.
You should also know that trying to do sessions using `session_start` for a RESTful API is NOT RESTful.

### Update due to Rajan's comment

This answer was just an explanation based on the question; you shouldn't think too much about it. To answer your question; look at the API key, and Auth key as 2 parts of a process that helps identify a user:

- one public: API key
- one private: Auth key

Every time you send a request, you send the public key, and a string generated from combining the public, and private key. The server takes the public key, searches for a valid private key, and tries to compute the value using the same formula, then finally compared what it generates, to what you generated.

If they're the same, it continues processing; if they're different, it terminates execution.

The validity of the session id above can be anything you want, usually it'll be long-lived (can probably last up to 30 days).

Comment: Since it has helped, you can mark this as the answer ;-)

Comment: first time i'm asking question so i did not know ,thank you for your help ,i marked as answer :)

Comment: i will not get the client details like IP and Browser they using and which device they using because request  made between server to server not between browser to server,so how i can get this details ,its possible without asking rest service requester?

Comment: You should check out the Wurfl project http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/. You can get all that information using it because Wurfl works by analysing the "User-Agent" header sent by the connecting client.

Comment: @EmmanuelOkeke What is the diffrence between auth key and api key ?  What are they used for ? And what should be the expected validity for session_id