# Login in Codeigniter through CURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, curl

I am trying to login into a CI site from a WP sub-domain, by calling an API end-point with the user and password.
The problem is that even if the API returns success with a valid user and password, when I am redirected to the CI site I am not detected as logged in because apparently there is no open session.

So, how do I make the API save the session so when the user reaches the CI site he/she is properly identified as logged in.

Sessions are stored in a table and I am making the request from the WP site like this:

```
// wp.mysite.com
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"ci.mysite.com/api/public/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);

// Here I find out if I am logged in or not
if ($server_output->success) {
    header("Location: ci.mysite.com/my");
}
```

and the API made in the CI site

```
// ci.mysite.com/api/public/login
<?php

class Login extends Api_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $email = Input::get('email_address');

        $user = new User();
        $user->where('email', $email)->get();

        if(!$user->exists()) {
            Data::set('error', 'User not found');
            $this->done();
        }

        $password = Input::get('password');

        if(!$user->checkPassword($password)) {
            Data::set('error', 'Login error');
            $this->done();
        }

        Data::set('user', $user->toArray());

        Session::login($user);
        $this->done();
    }
}
```

So, after login I expect the session to be open in the CI site but when I am redirected there, I find out I am not. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In API Implementation, when the user successfully logs in using his credentials, token must be returned in response and saved locally. This token will be used for later API calls' which again validate on server.

[Check this link for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514344/how-to-make-use-of-session-in-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the session info on your local storage that's why you you look like not logged in.

[check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php)